# QMainWindow not shown if functools.partial not used

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I show Second `QMainWindow` after click on button in parent `QMainWindow`

```
def on_click(self):
    window = second_window.MainWindow()
    window.show()
```

Second window not shown (Without any error). But if in Second window I add line:

```
self.func = functools.partial(self.some_func)
```

All work correct.

Why it's happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are creating the `window` as a local variable inside the `on_click` scope. As soon as `on_click` finishes the `window` attribute will be destroyed.

Try storing the window in an instance variable:

```
def on_click(self):
    self._window = second_window.MainWindow()
    self._window.show()
```

The `functools.partial` approach is probably working just because you are already storing it at the instance.